# Is the well-ordering principles only holding for the natural numbers?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I would like to know if the set of natural numbers is the only one where the well-ordering principle holds for the usual order relation ?

I have troubles understanding this

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Certainly any finite orderded set is well ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use the usual order relation, the sets
$$\{-k,-k+1,-k+2,...,0,1,2,3...\}$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ also satisfy the well-ordering principle. It is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ so it's not really a great example.

If you're willing to use other order relations, then any set can be well-ordered according to the axiom of choice. They can be made explicit on same cases (for instance in $\mathbb{Z}$) but usually not.

Comment: thanks i get it better now !